# Remove last pull github

Tags: git, github

I was working on `develop` branch. I committed my code and switched to another branch `feature/2.10.9`.
I had to take the latest from `feature/2.10.9`,but by mistake I run the following command

```
git pull origin develop
```

instead of

```
git pull origin feature/2.10.9
```

which pulled latest code from develop branch. And git status is showing following output:

```
On branch feature/2.10.9
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature/2.10.9' by 5 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

But I don't want to push `develop` branch changes to that `feature/2.10.9`. 
What should I do to abort current push.

Thanks

Comment: "$git checkout ."
U will lose your changes but you can switch branches again.

If you want to keep your changes use "$git stash"

Comment: @Mathias Dewelde:There are no any changes in my local, and Its not working still displaying 
`Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature/2.10.9' by 5 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)`

Comment: `git checkout` will not do anything as there are no files in the staging area. `pull` will merge the files directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to basically undo the merge done by running `git pull origin develop` instead of`git pull origin feature/2.10.9`.

First on your local, do a

`git reflog` to get the `SHA-1` of the commit before the faulty pull (the last stable state).

To undo the merge -

```
git reset --hard <SHA-1 of commit obtained above>
```

Note that all of this should be done while you are in the `feature/2.10.9` branch. After these steps you will be in the same state as you were before the incorrect merge. Now you can safely run `git pull origin feature/2.10.9` that will fetch and merge the latest from the remote  `feature/2.10.9`

Comment: @gravetii- Hey bro, Thanks worked this. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 5):

simply reset by one

```
git reset --hard HEAD^1
```